# swift Mailer - set To with PHP variables

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

Just looking at using Swift Mailer to send emails from Windows server. I have a short form with an input field which allows the web user to add in their email address (id is `email`), I need to be able to inject the `email` PHP variable into the `setTo` SwiftMailer code to allow the mail to be sent to the designated email address... Anyone know how to do this?

Basic code is

```
// Set the To addresses with an associative array
->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))
```

I need to get it to use `$email` rather than `receiver@domain.org`

Any ideas?

Comment: Be very careful if you are allowing the client to inject where the email is getting delivered. Spammers will probably get your server blacklisted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the posted value.

```
// Set the To addresses with an associative array
$email = $_POST['email'];
->setTo(array($email));
```

Assuming your HTML is similar to

```
<form method="post">
    Email: 
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email_id" />
</form>
```

Keep in mind that the `name` `input` attribute is what you will want to capture with PHP. The `id` is not passed to your PHP script.

[PHP Documentation - Dealing with Forms](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

[Swiftmail Creating Messages Documentation](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html)

Answer (score 0):

You mean you've got a `POST` or `GET` from which outputs the user's entered e-mail address in the field "email" (eg: `name="email"`)? Try this:

```
$mailer->setTo($_POST['email']);
```

The fun part is, you can use it with `name="email[]"`, where you can simply, again, pass along the `$_POST['email']` to `setTo` and you're done! :)

```
$mailer->setTo(array(
    'email-1@domain.tld' => 'Name 1',
    'email-2@domain.tld' => 'Name 2',
    'email-3@domain.tld' => 'Name 3',
    'email-4@domain.tld' => 'Name 4',
));
```

You can also use more examples, like combining `name="email[]"` with `name="name[]"` like so:

```
$mailer->setTo(array_combine($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']));
```

Note that for array_combine to work, you need two identical arrays of length. Secure your code like so (can be expanded to suite your needs):

```
$emails =& $_POST['emails'];
$names =& $_POST['name'];

if (count($emails) > count($names)) {
    $emails = array_slice($emails, 0, count($names));
} 

else if (count($names) > count($emails)) {
    $names = array_slice($names, 0, count($emails));
}

$mailer->setTo(array_combine($emails, $names));
```

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys - this method worked:

```
->setTo($email)
```